# buI am not able to run my program on emulator android studio.It says /dev/kvm not found (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-16.04

I am not  able to run my android application in android studio emulator.It says /dev/kvm not found (ubuntu 16.04).

On troubleshooting its says "Enable VT-x in your bios settings,ensure that your linux distro has working kvm module.

Any help would be appreciated!!